# Estou desenvolvendo um gerador de R.A. em python, e não estou conseguindo imprimir uma sequencia

Tags: python-3.x

Gerar uma sequencia de registro

```
lote = int ( input ( 'Digite o nº do lote: ' ) )
tipo = int ( input ( 'Digite o tipo da placa: ' ) )
sequencial = int ( input ( 'Digite a o primeiro nº: ' ) )

tipo1 = "{:04n}".format ( tipo )
sequencial1 = "{:05n}".format ( sequencial )

num = int ( lote + tipo + sequencial )

def digital_root(num) :
    x = sum ( int ( digit ) for digit in str ( num ) )
    if x < 10 :
        return x
    else :
        return digital_root ( x )

print('R.A.: ', lote, tipo1, sequencial1, digital_root ( num ))
```

**Exemplo**

*Entrada*

Digite o nº do lote: 28

Digite o tipo da placa: 100

Digite a o primeiro nº: 921

*Na saída print uma sequencia assim:*

R.A.: 28 0100 00921 5

R.A.: 28 0100 00922 6

R.A.: 28 0100 00923 7

R.A.: 28 0100 00924 8

R.A.: 28 0100 00925 9

R.A.: 28 0100 00926 1

R.A.: 28 0100 00927 2

R.A.: 28 0100 00928 3

R.A.: 28 0100 00929 4

R.A.: 28 0100 00930 5

Comment: Por favor, edite sua pergunta informando um exemplo de entrada pro seu código e qual é a saída. Essas informações não estão claras.

Answer (score -2):

O resultado desejado pode ser conseguido utilizando a seguinte função:

```
 print('R.A.: {} {} {} {}'.format(lote, tipo1, sequencial1, digital_root ( num )))
 # R.A.: 28 0100 00921 5
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Obrigado Danizavtz. Mas o resultado deveria dar uma sequencia igual ao exemplo que passei acima. com exceção dos espaços entre linhas.